# TFS build fails: The type X exists in both

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, build

We have a website (not webApp, framework 3.5) we are trying to build in our TFS build server.
The build is defined to trigger on each check-in. The build passed successfully on local machine (VS2010).
However, It fails to build on the TFS build server(2012) because of the following error:

> The type X exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files....\App_Web_wk4sskb7.dll' and
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files....\App_Web_wazvuwk6.dll'

We thought the reason for that is 2 MasterPages that inherits from the same page but we copied the same projects to a new solution and defined the same build definitions (under different TFS project) and the build was successful.

We want to figure out how is that possible, because this is not a suitable solution for us.
We want the original solution to pass successfully.

Comment: I would heavily recommend that you switch to a WebApplication from a Web site. You get these sort of issues much more rarely with WebApps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we have 2 MasterPages that had the same CodeFile.
We separated them and the build passed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

We got the same problem on several occassions when publishing a website. We always solved it by deleting the contents of the "bin" folder and re-publish the website.

I don't really know what is causing this problem in the .NET framework though. It would be nice if someone could explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not just a case of the temporary asp.net dll's being created when the website first spins up?
I'm assuming the .. contains a folder with the web site name
I've had issues before with similar things, try clearing the temporary folder and if that works, include a delete task as part of the build process

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear the bin folder
2. Build VS 2012

Build succeeded
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem when building in Azure CI Pipeline.
The issue was changing some of the Control Tag Names

**Current:**

```
<%@ Register Src="CustomerInfo.ascx" TagName="CustomerInfo" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

**Change to:**

```
<%@ Register Src="CustomerInfo.ascx" TagName="CustomerInfoA" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

Which resolved the issue.